# Устаревшее слово, означающее "позже, ничего страшного". Произносилось "анадсе" или "анадси"

Tags: устаревшие-слова

Бабушка употребляла "анадсе" (или близко к этому), когда хотела сказать, что что-то можно сделать потом, позже. "Надысь" также было в ее лексиконе, в значении "давеча", "вчера" и т. п.

Что это за слово?!

Answer (score 3):

Ваша бабушка употребляла диалектную версию просторечия [надысь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%8C&all=x), произнося анадысь!

К "ничего страшного" слово отношения не имеет.

---

Если [давеча](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/44106) - недавно (вчера или спозаранку, например), то надысь, как и намедни, - более раннее по времени, на днях.

[АНАГОДНИ](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/203314) — АНАГОДНИ, **АНАДЫСЬ**, АНАМНЯСЬ, АНАМЕДНИ, правильнее онагодни; см. намедни и аландась.

Толковый словарь Даля.

Comment: Galina Avanesova, нет. Это не было анадысь, так как было просто "надысь" в привычном значении "давеча", "вчера" и т.п. Это было другое слово. Я нашел его на форумах Рязани и Липецка, в частности. Наши "современники" используют  это слово - "анатся" в значении "ну и ладно" или "пусть так и будет".